# Separator in my results

Tags: php, mysql

This query works fine for me, it gets my results and echos them back. But what I am missing and can not get to work is to get a separator in between the results. I have tried to use the implode function but was unable to. What I would like is a "|" in between the results in the echo. Below is my code I am using, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxxxxxx", $user_name, $password, $database_name);
if (!$dbh)
{
    die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error($dbh));
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT value FROM `$table_name` WHERE field IN('$field1', '$field2')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbh,$query);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "NO_DATA_FOUND"; 
    } 
    else
    {
    while ($result_list = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    echo '' .$result_list["value"] . '';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbh);                        
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of echoing in the `while` loop, build an array, then `echo implode('|', $dataArray);` after the `while`.  `$dataArray = array(); while(...){ $dataArray[] = $result_list["value"]; }`

Comment: You can use GROUP_CONCAT expression in your sql query like this -
GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR "|"). 

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') AS new_value FROM .....

Comment: Thank you! I used Rockets method and it worked like a charm.